# How to open a web page from WPF?

Tags: c#

Using Visual Studio 2019 WPF app
Trying to open a web page with code that has worked for me before but i get an error now

I get an error message saying
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

Also want to open the page in Chrome

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Diagnostics;

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Process.Start("https://www.google.com");

    }
```

Comment: try https instead of http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using .net core. You should pass `ProcessStartInfo` to `Process.Start()`. If you want the default browser to open, you can call cmd to do the work for you. If you want a specific browser, you can provide the process name for that browser as well.

For default browser, you can do something like

```
string url = "https://www.google.com";
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}") { CreateNoWindow = true });
```

Comment: That works Thanks  --  
How could i get the web page to open in Chrome

Comment: This is the code that actually works. There are some other responses where "Explorer" is called using a url as parameter, that approach fails sometimes when url contains querystring parameters.

Answer (score -1):

To open a URL in Chrome, populate the ProcessStartInfo() class properties as in the following:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "https://www.google.com";

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            // To open url in Chrome, specify startInfo.File = "chrome.exe"
            // To open url in FireFox specify firefox.exe
            // To open url in Microsoft Edge specify msedge.exe
            // To open url in default browser specify explorer.exe

            startInfo.FileName = "chrome.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = url;
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This relies on a particular browser to be installed on user machine (and being on the path too). Relying on such things is a bad practice, instead use whatever they have as the "default" browser and let it handle the url.

Comment: Jamal - I like your code and i did try to run it but when it gets to the Process.Start it gives me the original error that i was getting - I get an error message saying System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.' - perhaps im missing a reference but i dont know hoe to diagnose it, can you help?? 
   Thanks

Comment: @Bigshop, could you create a fresh WPF app and see what happens. Maybe you are missing some references. I commented earlier to do that, but some character deleted my comments!