# How to redirect to a Website from a Button click in a desktop app WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've seen everyone recomending the following:

```
        private void RegisterBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://website.com/");
        }
```

But I get the following error:

"The system cannot find the file specified." System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"

I want for the button to open a window in the default browser.

Ps: It's a WPF desktop App coded in C#

Comment: See here: Have you a browser installed and a default browser is set ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/start-internet-browser

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Yes, I have Google Chrome as my default browser. But regardless of that, even if the user doesn't have a default browser set, is there a simple way of opening a website from the WPF?

Comment: This is the simple way. Please read the whole article, it explains why you get that exception

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Using the try-catch from this article it says i don't have a browser, but I do. So the only thing I believe it can be is something related to this HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. But even so, this doesn't seems to be a reliable way of opening a website from the WPF, cause even with me having a browser and set to the defaul, it doesn't work...

Comment: If you type in `https://website.com/` in the Run dialog (Windows+R) or a cmd window: does it work?

Comment: If there is no default browser, which application do you want to use for navigating to the URL...?

Comment: @KlausGütter If i type ```explorer "https://www.website.com/"``` in the cmd, it works perfeclty, that's exactly what I wish i could do when the button was clicked. It opens the website with my default browser which is Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i've found this answer: [How to open a web page from WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856693/how-to-open-a-web-page-from-wpf)

And that does exactly what I asked, Idk how to link that answer to this one.
But here's the code:

```
private void RegisterBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string url = "https://www.website.com";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}") { CreateNoWindow = true });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `explorer.exe` explicitly: 
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", url);`
or you can use it in try catch block:

```
try
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
}
catch (Win32Exception ex)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore.exe", url);
}
```

Comment: What if there is no IExplorer in the target computer ?

Comment: You are trying to start a new process in the catch part of a try catch. Please explain how that is a good idea ?